# json_encode url fail

Tags: php, zend-framework, json

Has anyone way around [this bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49366)?

```
echo json_encode(array('url'=>'/foo/bar'));
{"url":"\/foo\/bar"}
```

I use [Zend_Json and Zend_Json_Expr](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.advanced.html#zend.json.advanced.expr) so I can get even callback functions inside my js object -- but I can't get a url to come out in a usable format!

```
echo Zend_Json::encode(array(
                         'url'=>new Zend_Json_Expr('/foo/bar'),
                       ), false,
                       array(
                         'enableJsonExprFinder' => true),
                       ));
```

produces:

```
{"url":/foo/bar}
```

which obviously isn't right either..

Is there anyway to get:

```
{"url":"/foo/bar"}
```

without having to do anything ridiculous like find a way to regex it out before sending it to stdio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{"url":"\/foo\/bar"}` is actually completely valid and correct JSON for "/foo/bar". Try decoding that value using `json_decode()` or `Zend_Json::decode()` and it should output your original URL correctly.

Comment: yes, it is correct JSON, and upon further investigation window.location = 'http:\/\/www.google.com\/'; seems to work.. looks like it's as bug in the plugin i'm using :-p

Comment: And, using _Expr essentially just tells the encoder to not put it in quotes or escape the value - much like Zend_Db_Expr.